# mysql calculate debt and deposit base on two columns

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table with the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE tblapp (
  `app_id` INTEGER,
  `cust_id` INTEGER,
  `app_price` INTEGER,
  `app_price_paid` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO tblapp
  (`app_id`, `cust_id`, `app_price`, `app_price_paid`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '100', '100'),
  ('2', '2', '50', '0'),
  ('3', '1', '0', '100'),
  ('4', '3', '100', '50');
```

And I have the following sql and output:

```
SELECT 
cust_id,
(sum(COALESCE(app_price,0)) - sum(COALESCE(app_price_paid,0))) as total
FROM tblapp
group by cust_id;

| cust_id | total |
| ------- | ----- | 
| 1       | -100  |
| 2       |   50  |
| 3       |   50  |
|---------|-------|
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qkY8JdoRC9pwTWSZKxEvat/2)

Base on the above, if I calculate the total debt is 0 (sum of total(-100 + 50 + 50)).

But the real debt is 100 ( 50 + 50 ) and the deposit is 100 ( -100 ).

Can I have a query to output the below table base on my data?

```
 debt  deposit
 100     100
```

Thank you.

debt = how must money need to paid.

deposit = how much money has paid more.

Comment: You have added a row `('3', '1', '0', '100'),` with a Price of ZERO and a Payment of 100?? That sounds a little ODD. So Cust 1 is in credit by 100

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, as the customer pre paid for something. So this is deposit. Paid in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use aggregation one more time:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT cust_id,
         (sum(COALESCE(app_price,0)) - sum(COALESCE(app_price_paid,0))) as total
   FROM tblapp
  group by cust_id
)
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN total< 0 THEN -total END) AS debt,
       SUM(CASE WHEN total>= 0 THEN total END) AS deposit
FROM cte;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=84e073b2dc0aa2071fae76143e7af121)**

Comment: can we do it without cte for older versions of MySQL and MariaDB. As a second option.

Comment: Simple replace the CTE with `(query here) cte`